# Cancel/Block the save of a domain object based on some criteria?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

i have a need to block or cancel a save of a domain object based on some property.
Can this be done in a constraint?

Example:
An 'Order' domain object has a state of 'invoiced' then the order should not be able to be  updated anymore..

Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no reason why you couldn't simply use a constraint for this (as you suggested). Something like this should do it

```
class Order {

  String state

  static constraints = {

    state(validator: {stateValue, self ->

      // only check state if this object has already been saved
      if (self.id && stateValue == 'invoiced') {
        return false
      }
    })
  }
}
```

If for some reason you can't use a constraint, here are a couple of alternative suggestions:

### Meta-Programming

Use Groovy's method-interception capabilities to intercept calls to `save()`. Your interceptor should only forward the call to the intercepted `save()` if the order does not have an invoiced state.

There are some good examples of how to do this in the [Programming Groovy](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Groovy-Productivity-Developer-Programmers/dp/1934356093/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1322648483&sr=1-1) book

### GORM Events

GORM provides a number of [events](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/5.%20Object%20Relational%20Mapping%20%28GORM%29.html#5.5.1%20Events%20and%20Auto%20Timestamping) that are triggered during a persisted objects lifecycle. It may be possible in the `beforeUpdate` or `beforeValidate` events to prevent updating the object (I guess throwing an exception would work)

Comment: The GORM event triggered beforeUpdate will probably be the best bet. User can also implement a custom SaveOrUpdate event listener.

Comment: @VisionarySoftwareSolutions you're right, it should be `beforeUpdate` instead of `beforeInsert`, but I don't know if there's any way to prevent the update within the event listener other than throwing an exception